# Parsing int does not work for some odd reason

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a second form that pops up upon clicking a button, a user can input some parameters for a method, save the input within a variable, and then I parse the result to an int ( thus so I can utilize it within my method ). Now, upon parsing it, the value appears to be `NULL` as oppose to what the user inputted within the textboxes.

```
  var displayproperties = new int[3];
            using (Form2 form = new Form2())
            {
                try
                {
                    if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                    {
                        int i = 0;
                        while (i == 0) 
                        {
                        if (form.click) // ok button is clicked
                        {
                            // parse values
                            displayproperties[0] = int.Parse(form.Height);
                            displayproperties[1] = int.Parse(form.Width);
                            displayproperties[2] = int.Parse(form.Framerate);
                            goto break_0; // break out of loop ( loop is to check when button is clicked )
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

As you can see here, the values that the user inputs is `Height`,`Width` and `Framerate` respectively. It parses it to an int, as I explained, and stores it in the `displayproperties` int array.
This is the second form:

```
 public string Height { get; set; }
        public string Width { get; set; }
        public string Framerate { get; set; }

        public bool click = false; 
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){}
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Height = height.Text; 
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Width = width.Text; 
        }

        private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Framerate = framerate.Text; 
        }

        public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            click = true;            
        }
```

Ultimately, the values are then passed into this class:
`public Class1(int width, int height)`
However I get an out of range exception saying the value must be greater than zero. Goes without saying, the values I inputted were certainly greater than zero ( 800, 600, 60 respectively ) where `60` is used elsewhere.

Comment: Why don't you assign `Width`, `Height`, and `Framerate`  in `OK_Click`?

Comment: By the way your loop "to check when button is clicked" makes absolutely no sense. `ShowDialog()` blocks until the form closes, so you'll never reach that piece of code until the form is closed. Not to mention that the correct way to leave the loop wold be to use the `break;` keyword.

Comment: Why would I want to do that though? Is there any benefit to doing that, I can still reference these variables publicly for ease of access and I theoretically should still be able to assign values to them regardlessly? But most importantly, will it solve my problem? I don't see how.

Comment: @John Frankly, I didn't know that. I'm quite ignorant to WinForms and just started about yesterday.

Comment: @John do you have a better implementation to check when the OK button is clicked.

Comment: An integer can't be null. Consider using `int.TryParse` to parse your user input; using `int.Parse` will throw an exception on a user typo. Consider changing you `click` member name. Forms already have an event named `Click`, it's confusing to the reader

Comment: My understanding was that assuming the form was opened, all code within the if statement would be executed, at least, that is how it behaved. And assuming that was the case ( which upon first inspection it was ) I decided to put a while loop to constantly update the variables with the user input variables, however, I only wanted it to check assuming the OK button was pressed. So, I checked when the OK button was pressed through a boolean ( as you saw implemented in the code ), upon the if statement being true ( the click boolean ), it would update the variables and break out of the loop.

Comment: @Flydog57 That is why I have a try catch block. Are you suggesting that will not suffice?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the line `if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)` and step through with the debugger to observe the behaviour. `ShowDialog()` will block (as in the next lines of code will not be executed) until it returns, which only happens when the form is closed.

Comment: @John Your suggestion worked to no avail unfortunately. It still persists on giving me the 
OutOfRange exception saying that the values must be greater than zero. I took out the while loop and everything, simply left the  ```if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)``` line and it appears that upon closing the form, and according to you when it thus saves the variables, and utilizes said variables, the values are still not being updated.

Comment: @Mike, avoiding an exception is **_way_** better than catching one. Exceptions, when thrown, are big, heavy and slow. You can often tell when an exception is thrown in your code because it feels slower

Comment: Try adding `this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK; this.Close();` in your `OK_Click` method.

Comment: Oh, thanks, @John! Looks like that did it! I can consider your comment an answer if you post an answer! Thanks again! 

Kindest Regards, Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment suggestion worked for you, I'll add it as an answer.

From what you've said, it sounds likely that you're not setting `DialogResult` anywhere, so your if statement is never being entered because the condition isn't met.

You should set the dialog result and close the form in `OK_Click`:

```
public void OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    this.Close();       
}
```

And then you should remove the extra code from your main form:

```
var displayproperties = new int[3];
using (Form2 form = new Form2())
{
    try
    {
        if (form.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // parse values
            displayproperties[0] = int.Parse(form.Height);
            displayproperties[1] = int.Parse(form.Width);
            displayproperties[2] = int.Parse(form.Framerate);
        }
    }
}
```

The dialog result will serve as your `click` property so this is no longer required. By the way, I recommend switching to [`TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead so that you can actively check if the input values are valid integers, as opposed to leaving it until exceptions are thrown.

An example of this:

```
string a = "hello"; // substitute user input here
int result;
if (!int.TryParse(a, out result))
{
    MessageBox.Show($"{a} isn't a number!");
    return;
}

MessageBox.Show($"Your integer is {result}");
```

If you're newish to programming, I recommend getting familiar with how to use the debugger. Setting a breakpoint and inspecting values as you stepped through the code would have revealed where the problem was very quickly. Microsoft have a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger?view=vs-2019) for this.

Comment: Thanks, quite frankly, I wasn't aware of what you referring to when you referenced the debugger. Thanks for sending me that link!

Comment: @Mike I honestly wasn't until I started working professionally, even having been a hobbyist programmer for quite a while prior. Once you get used to using it, it's really useful for finding problems.